# executing a curl request through bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have to insert many data in my application and through the graphical interface it takes many time. For this reason I want to create a bash script and make the requests through curl using the REST API (I have to manually specify the id).

The problem is that i get the error: **The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.**

Here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash   

for i in {1..1}
do                                                                                                                                                                                  
CURL='/usr/bin/curl -X POST'
RVMHTTP="http://192.168.1.101:8080/sitewhere/api/devices 
  -H 'accept:application/json' 
  -H 'content-type:application/json' 
  -H 'x-sitewhere-tenant:sitewhere1234567890' 
  --user admin:password"

DATA=" -d  '{\"hardwareId":\"$i",\"siteToken\":\"4e6913db-c8d3-4e45-9436-f0a99b502d3c\",\"specificationToken\":\"82043707-9e3d-441f-bdcc-33cf0f4f7260\"}'"

# or you can redirect it into a file:
$CURL $RVMHTTP $DATA >> /home/bluedragon/Desktop/tokens
done
```

The format of my request has to be json

Comment: BTW -- http://shellcheck.net/ is a resource you may find useful; try fixing what it finds (and reading the wiki pages linked to each error when you don't understand the reasoning behind the advice / when the advice appears to make things worse) before asking questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rvmcurl() {
  local url
  url="http://192.168.1.101:8080/sitewhere/${1#/}"
  shift || return # function should fail if we weren't passed at least one argument
  curl -XPOST "${rvm_curl_args[@]}" "$url" "$@"
}

i=1 # for testing purposes

rvm_curl_args=(
  -H 'accept:application/json' 
  -H 'content-type:application/json' 
  -H 'x-sitewhere-tenant:sitewhere1234567890' 
  --user admin:password
)

data=$(jq -n --arg hardwareId "$i" '
{
      "hardwareId": $hardwareId,
      "siteToken": "4e6913db-c8d3-4e45-9436-f0a99b502d3c",
      "specializationToken": "82043707-9e3d-441f-bdcc-33cf0f4f7260"
}')

rvmcurl /api/devices -d "$data"
```

Note:

- **Commands, or command fragments intended to be parsed into multiple words, should *never* be stored in strings**. Use an array or a function instead. Quotes inside such strings are not parsed as syntax, and instead (when parsed without `eval`, which carries its own [serious risks and caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) become literal values. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a full explanation.
- Use a JSON-aware tool, such as `jq`, to ensure that generated data is legit JSON.
- Fully-qualifying paths to binaries is, in general, an antipattern. It doesn't result in a significant performance gain (the shell caches PATH lookups), but it *does* reduce your scripts' portability and flexibility (preventing you from installing a wrapper for `curl` in your PATH, in an exported shell function, or otherwise).
- All-caps variable names are in a namespace [used for variables with meaning to the shell and operating system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html). Use names with at least one lowercase character for your own variables to prevent any chance of conflict.

Comment: that is beautiful

Comment: Now the problem is http status 400 - incompleteData: not all required data was provided.

Here is how i want to request (Taken from postman), it works on Postman and if inserted directly in in the bash

curl -X POST 
  http://192.168.1.101:8080/sitewhere/api/devices 
  -H 'accept: application/json' 
  -H 'content-type: application/json' 
  -H 'x-sitewhere-tenant: sitewhere1234567890' 
  --user admin:password
  -d '{
  "hardwareId" : "xxx",
  "siteToken" : "4e6913db-c8d3-4e45-9436-f0a99b502d3c",
  "specificationToken" : "82043707-9e3d-441f-bdcc-33cf0f4f7260"
}'

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript`, and compare the commands it emits in the log to the ones you want.

Comment: It was a typo problem with "specializationToken". 

I did not notice yesterday. Thank you very much for the help :)